# PHP Class auto run method

Tags: php, class, oop

I don't know if the title is really correct for what I'm asking, but here it goes. I'm trying to build a **very basic** pagination class, just for retrieving a range of items.
This is my class so far

```
<?php

    Class Pagination {

        private $_dbh;

        private $_currentPage;

        private $_totalPages;

        private $_startLimit;

        private $_totalItems;

        private $_table = 'products';

        private $_perPage = 8;

        private $_allowedTables = ['products', 'cart', 'orders'];

        public $_results = [];


        public function __construct($dbh = null) {
            $this->_dbh = ($dbh !== null) ? $dbh : null;
        }


        public function getResults() {
            $this->_results = $this->_dbh->query(" SELECT * FROM $this->_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $this->_startLimit, $this->_perPage ")->fetchAll();
        }


        public function setCurrentPage($currentPage = null) {
            $this->_currentPage = ($currentPage !== null && is_int($currentPage)) ? $currentPage : 1;
        }


        public function setPerPage($perPage = null) {
            $this->_perPage = ($perPage !== null && is_int($perPage)) ? $perPage : $this->_perPage;
        }


        public function setTable($table = null) {
            $this->_table = ($table !== null && in_array($table, $this->_allowedTables)) ? $table : $this->_table;
        }

        private function totalItems() {
            $this->_totalItems = $this->_dbh->query(" SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM $this->_table")->fetch()->total;
        }


        private function totalPages() {
            $this->_totalPages = ceil($this->_totalItems / $this->_perPage);
        }


        private function startLimit() {
            $this->_startLimit = ( $this->_currentPage - 1 ) * $this->_perPage;
        }


        public function getInfo() {
            return array(
                'table'         => $this->_table,
                'perPage'       => $this->_perPage,
                'currentPage'   => $this->_currentPage,
                'totalItems'    => $this->_totalItems,
                'totalPages'    => $this->_totalPages,
                'startLimit'    => $this->_startLimit,
                'query'         => " SELECT * FROM $this->_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $this->_startLimit, $this->_perPage "
            );
        }


    }

?>
```

It is incomplete, but this is how I would like to call it

```
$pagination = new Pagination($dbh); // $dbh = PDO connection
$pagination->setCurrentPage(2);
$pagination->setTable('products'); // optional
$pagination->setPerPage(12); // optional
$products = $pagination->_results();
```

The problem is that all the variables that I define at the top of my class ( `$_currentPage, $_totalPages, $_startLimit and $_totalItems` ) are empty.

Even when I set them, they are still empty(as I expect) so I cannot calculate the `$_totalPages`, `$_startLimit`, `$_totalItems` or call the method `getResults()` which will query the DB for the items.

The first approach was to do everything in the `__construct` method and it worked, but I feel like it's not good to perform too many actions inside one method.

So my question is how can I modify my class so I can use it as I showed even without calling the `setter` methods ?

Plus, all the methods that calculate the number of pages, total items, etc.., would have to be called automatically from inside the class so they actually set the variables values, the way it is now they are only available but aren't run anywhere.

Thank you.

Comment: Set default values for those properties

Comment: It's not possbile because all those values are calculated and are based on the current page and the total items in the DB

Comment: "So my question is how can I modify my class so I can use it as I showed even without calling the setter methods ?" What do you mean by this exactly? Do you want to set the properties directly? Do you want a single magic method that can set any of the properties?

Comment: In the end I figured I would call all the methods inside the getResults() method. I wanted to be able to calculate the variables without calling the respective method. For example to calculate how many pages I will have but without calling explicitly the totalPages() method.